# No module named 'requests', yet installed already

Tags: python, python-requests

I know this question has been asked many times here, but none of the posts solve my issue.
So I ran "import requests" and got `No module named 'requests'` every time.
Even have I checked my `pip3 list` and tried to uninstall and reinstall, still.

```
C:\Users\exit0\Google Drive\Python4evbd\Yelp>pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\exit0\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\exit0\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests) (3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\exit0\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\exit0\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests) (1.26.6)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\exit0\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests) (2021.5.30)

C:\Users\exit0\Google Drive\Python4evbd\Yelp>yelp_parse.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\exit0\Google Drive\Python4evbd\Yelp\yelp_parse.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

C:\Users\exit0\Google Drive\Python4evbd\Yelp>pip list
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
certifi            2021.5.30
charset-normalizer 2.0.4
idna               3.2
pip                21.2.4
requests           2.26.0
urllib3            1.26.6
```

Does anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: [pip install requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

Comment: To be clear, the output you show is what you get when you use `pip list`? And you're **certain** that when you try the code `import requests`, it is using the *same installation of Python* (here, a virtual environment is a separate "installation") that `pip list` and `python --version` are using? Because otherwise, unless you can give complete, exact steps to reproduce that start from a new computer that doesn't have Python, and other people successfully reproduce from that, I don't think it's possible to help.

Comment: Are you using [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)? Make sure that the python environment you are using is the one with the installed `requests`.

Comment: "but none of the posts solve my issue" Specifically which posts did you look at (link them)? Specifically what did advice did you take from them (quote from answers)? Specifically what did you do based on that advice? Exactly what happened when you did that?

Comment: In particular, note that if you create a virtual environment and *then* installed `requests` to the system Python, that will *not necessarily* show up as installed in the virtual environment. Depending on your platform, a virtual environment can either use symlinks or a whole separate copy of the executables, libraries etc.

Comment: Hi @KarlKnechtel  @Niel,  I am not using a virtual environment. I got the list from using `pip list`. I checked `pip list` and `python --version` in the Command Prompt and open my .py file then got `File "C:\Users\exit0\Google Drive\Python4evbd\Yelp\yelp_parse.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`.

Comment: Do `python yelp_parse.py` instead of just file name. Using just file name uses whatever program is linked to .py extension in your system which might not be the correct version. (You can check python version from the script itself by doing `print(sys.version)` before it breaks, of course import sys for that.)

Comment: To add to @h4z3's suggestion, if you use `python -m pip install requests` and `python yelp_parse.py`, then you will know for sure that you're using the same environment for both calls.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a virtual environment？
if you install requests in virtual environment, you need active the virtual environment first

you can try in cmd:

```
➜  ~ python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31)
>>> import requests
>>>
```

input `python`  in cmd , if OK，and output python version
input `import requests` , enter
if not wrong ,it's ok

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Fixed it by doing the following:
`pip install --upgrade requests`

Comment: Suggestions to try something are hardly answers.